# Will the new open source Broadcom drivers be available in the current LTS release?

Tags: 10.04, wireless, kernel

I [just found out](http://lwn.net/Articles/404248/) that Broadcom has released a set of open source drivers for their wireless cards. I know that the Ubuntu kernel team keeps a package of backported drivers for LTS 10.04.

Is the driver mature enough to be included in an update for LTS users, or will they have to wait for 10.10?

Update for users who might be affected: [How can I tell if I have a broadcom wireless card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4000/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-a-broadcom-wireless-card)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As it stands currently (unless something drastic happens), yes. We expect this to land in the `compat-wireless` package as soon as it has been approved. The current plan is to bring it in to Maverick (10.10) in this way and then, potentially, to backport to Lucid (10.04)

~JFo

Comment: Great to hear it from the highest authority instead of various guesswork.