# Broadcom open source drivers available in Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, broadcom, open-source

I have a laptop with a broadcom BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n wireless adapter and its using the proprietary STA drivers (perfectly), however I thought broadcom released open source drivers and that they would be included in Maverick (as according to [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3929/will-the-new-open-source-broadcom-drivers-be-available-in-the-current-lts-release)). How do I activate these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They weren't included in Maverick proper due to the timing of release.  As Jeremy stated, they're being considered for inclusion as part of upstream compat-wireless, and they have not yet landed in compat-wireless (they're only in staging currently), hence they have not landed in `linux-backports-modules-2.6.35` yet.  (You can track the [Ubuntu Maverick git tree](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-maverick-lbm.git/.git;a=tree;f=updates/net;hb=HEAD).)

So, the short answer is that as of today they're unavailable, so you can't easily apt-get install them from an official Ubuntu Maverick repository.  Please be patient.  (Alternately, you could compile the drivers in staging manually, but that's beyond the scope of this question.)

Comment: That makes a load of sense, I had misunderstood Jeremy comments about compat-wireless to meaning the maverick version and not the upstream package. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can install them manually, they are available.

Git the files - git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/gregkh/staging-next-2.6.git
And they're located in /drivers/staging/brcm80211

Comment: Thanks! I was already doing so but I was hoping there was wondering if there was an easier way to go about it.